# Getting StyleCop rule SA1503 CurlyBracketsMustNotBeOmitted to be more flexible

Tags: stylecop

I am having a hard time with StyleCop rule SA1503 (CurlyBracketsMustNotBeOmitted).

In my code I quite often have a pattern thus:

```
public void SomeFunction(string someArg)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someArg)) throw new ArgumentNullException("someArg");

    // rest of the function here
}
```

The rationale behind this is to save vertical space when doing multiple validation checks on a single argument and/or checks on many arguments. The logic in such a check is typically simple and concise and likewise for the exception that gets thrown.

However, I would *never* write

```
if (someConditional)
    DoSomeStuff();
```

I would always write

```
if (someConditional)
{
    DoSomeStuff();
}
```

So in summary:

- Use curly brackets if the if statement is split across multiple lines
- Don't use curly brackets for simple argument validation etc that can be easily (and readably) put on one line

Can StyleCop help me here?

Comment: @Richard E: what did you eventually end up doing? I don't want to dissable the rule, but I wish to write my preconditions like the pattern you describe.

Comment: @Lieven: For the time being we have left this rule on and decided to use curly brackets on our one line conditionals. To this end we turned off StyleCop rule SA1501.

Comment: OffTopic: don't throw ArgumentNullException if variable is empty string, you should use it only for null parameters

Comment: @VitaliyUlantikov - what exception would you throw for an empty string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already mentioned, unfortuntely StyleCop rules are either on or off and can't be customised. It would be nice to have a simple way of customising rules but unfortunately you'll need to write them from scratch.

The way I've used StyleCop is to focus on using as many of the built in rules as possible and where I really have a fundamental issue with a rule (code documentation, for example), I just turn it off. I'm not concerned enough about the exceptions to go to the extent of writing custom rules.

Comment: totally agree; we have found that a few weeks of adjusting to a "just do what stylecop says and stop arguing with it" attitude has led to many years of stress-free, highly readable code.

Answer (score 3):

StyleCop (and I agree here) wants you to split this into multiple lines.  It doesn't like if statements on one line, for (arguably) good reason - this causes an inconsistent usage pattern for if statements, which is one of the reasons that rule exists in the first place.

To get the behavior you're showing, you'd likely need to use the SDK to write your own customized rule for that specific case, and then disable the default rule.

Comment: mind elaborating on what the good reason is? I have preferred using single line if statements at the start of functions for a long time. ex: `if (data.empty) return;` Looks a bit odd as 3 lines.

Comment: @basher As mentioned " this causes an inconsistent usage pattern for if statements" - whether that's a problem or not is arguable, but it's a potentially valuable reason

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks Reed.